# Return List To View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, viewbag

Every Time I loop through the viewbag it gives this error

> object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

This My Action

```
public ActionResult AssignTask() 
{
    var List = db.Employees.Select(x => new 
    { 
        id = x.id, 
        Name = x.Name
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.Emp_data = List;

    return View();
}
```

and this is my view 
[image]

Comment: Your passing an anonymous object!. Create a view model with those properties and project your query into the view model. And pass the model to the view (do not use `ViewBag`). And show your code, not images of it

Comment: i am sorry i am new to stack overflow and i don't know how to put HTML code in text area

Comment: You copy the code in your view (the code in the image) into the question, just as you have done for the controller code

Comment: stack Overflow Removes my tags but i will try again thanks

Comment: Indent your code 4 spaces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code returns a `List<anonymous>`

```
var List = db.Employees.Select(x => new 
{ 
    id = x.id, 
    Name = x.Name
}).ToList();
```

so that's why you can't access `Name` property in the `foreach` loop in your view.

I would suggest using a strongly typed ViewModel class to hold the data and avoiding ViewBag. The ViewModel should be in Models folder and look like below

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Change your controller as below

```
public ActionResult AssignTask() 
{
    var model = db.Employees.Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel
    { 
        ID = x.id, 
        Name = x.Name
    }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

and in your view

```
@model List<EmployeeViewModel>

<h2>AssignTask</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div style="overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height:400px;">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <label>@item.Name</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="SelectEmp" value="@item.ID" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an anonymous type which the view doesn't know about.
You should still use your `Employee` class in your select:

```
    var List = db.Employees.Select(x => new Employee
    { 
        id=x.id,
        Name=x.Name
    }).ToList();
```

By the way, you should use a View Model instead of the viewbag to carry the data.