# How do you pass data to a partial view with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

*Disclaimer: I am new to ASP.NET Core but have read and tried a lot.*

I am trying to implement my first partial view and pass data to it. From what I have read, this should work so I am confused as to where things are going south.

**My Partial View:**

```
    @page
    @model int
    @*

   *@
   <h2>@Model</h2>
```

**My call to the partial view:**

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductCreate", 0);
```

**C# code for _ProductCreate is the default:**

```
public class _ProductCreateModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

`@Model` is always null. Specifically, I get the following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. aspnetcoreapp.Pages.Customers.Pages_Customers__ProductCreate.get_Model()

Comment: If you remove `@page` directive everything will work fine (but this is not an actual solution). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156162/7775908)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller associated to the view you need to return the model to the view. This is shown in the thread here: [Return List To View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180931/return-list-to-view).

Below is a simplified way to pass a model to the view where Example is my model type.

```
    public ActionResult HomeController(Example model)
    { 
        return View(model);
    }
```

If you then were in the view for Home you can pass the same model or a property of the model to a partial view like so:

```
@* Declaring your model *@
@model Example.Web.Models.Example

@* Passing that same model through to the partial view *@
@Html.Partial("_ProductCreate", Model);
```